# Methods separation in classes

Tags: c#, class, methods

I'm not really sure what this is called but I was wondering how to do things like:

```
Bank.Items
Bank.Money
```

and then there would be the methods there like

```
Bank.Money.getMoney();
Bank.Money.setMoney(500);
```

If some could at least tell me what to be looking up for that it would help.

Comment: Sounds like namespaces to me

Comment: To answer your question on what to look up, you're thinking of "class properties" or "member data". [Using Properties (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx)

Comment: The get and set things where just examples, there needs to be methods like adding, removing, getting names, getting the data, splitting the data, etc

Answer (score 2):

You could simply make `Money` a property of `Bank` and get getters and setters for free.

For instance:

```
public class Bank { 
  public decimal Money { get; set; }
}
```

But this being a bank, you're likely to going to need something more complex, in which case you can do logic in the body of the getter and setter, but you'll need to manage storage:

```
private decimal money;
public decimal Money {
  get {
    // do something here
    return money;
  }
  set {
    // and or here
    money = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, with auto-implemented properties, kinda.

Comment: Since OP appears new to coding, it may be useful to clarify that `get` and `set` aren't called like methods. You create a `Bank` object: `Bank myBank = new Bank();`, set `Money`: `myBank.Money = 500;`, and get `Money`: `decimal somethingElse = myBank.Money;`

Comment: I'm not new and the get and set were examples of methods I am using, I want something like in visual C# you can do Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); how do I make it so I can do Class.whatever.method

Comment: @MichaelGuercia Sorry, I guessed since you asked about property getters and setters that you might be new. I don't understand your new question. This answers exactly what is in your OP.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is to create a Money class??

```
class MoneyClass
{
    private decimal MoneyValue;

    public decimal getmoney()
    { return MoneyValue; }

    public setmoney(decimal Value)
    { MoneyValue = Value; }
}

class Bank
{
    public MoneyClass Money;
}
```

Or you could put money as a property in bank:

```
class Bank
{
    public Money {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: No. Money should NOT be its own class, neither should `getmoney` and `setmoney` be implemented like that. Both absolutely unnecessary. Your last code snippet is fine, but Grant's implementation with `private money` and `public Money` is best and represents the most common coding practice.

Comment: I have a class called Bank_Class I know how to make the methods and all of that I just want to organize it in a way that I can get an instance of the class as "Bank" and then do Bank.Money and call those methods and the. Bank.Items and call those methods

Comment: @MichaelGuercia Yes, see Grant's solution

Comment: I understand my answer wasn't good. Ok.

Comment: But is it fair to vote down when the question is not clear enough?

Comment: @Daniel Regardless of the question's clarity (I think it's perfectly clear), a downvote indicates a sub-optimal or low quality solution. Quite frankly, this solution sucks. Despite the limited detail of the question, I can't possibly fathom a situation that would ever warrant creating an entirely new class just to represent a decimal value.

Comment: @Michael Guercia. Have you tried nested classes? Inside the Bank class you can declare a Money (or any other) class, it's a nested class. The nested classes will have access to anything inside the "bank".